# Using Toastr, how can I create a very different looking toast from default (what are my options?)

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, angular9, toastr

I am using Angular 9 and ngx-toastr

I have the task of using toastr to create a set of toasts which look quite different from the default toast styles. Each in the set are basically the same, except for border colour, fontawesome icon and message (which I can just pass in).

Here is one of the toast mockups: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqLOs.png)

Toastr has it's own toastr.css style sheet which I added to angular.json. Without it, toasts won't even open. I have my own toast-messages.scss file that contains all the css to realize my mockup. I will include it. It's also added to angular.json

```
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/app/styles/toast-messages.scss"
            ],
```

What I find is that unless every line in my toast-messages.scss file needs an **!important** in it for it to override what's in the toastr.css and you know that's horrible.

**my question**
What are my options to create this style of toast without using all these !important tags in my css. Am I referencing the css/scss files in the wrong spot? Should I create a custom toast and if so, is there a good resource for that? I am only 2 months into Angular.

toast-messages.scss  **I know my formatting is horrible, this has been trial and error**

```
.toast-container .ngx-toastr {
  position: relative;
  width: 888px;
  height: 79px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 60px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.toast-container .ngx-toastr:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #000000 ;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer ;
}


.toast-container {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.toast-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

  .toast-message {
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 2px;
    width: 886px;
    height: 75px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }

.message-boxy {
  top: 2px;
  width: 886px;
  height: 75px;
}

.message-symbol {
  background-color: #800017;
  width: 79px;
   height: 75px;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0px;
}

.message-symbol i {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  transform: translateY(0.7em);
}

.toast-text-container {
  position: relative;
  width:886px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: #FFAE15;
  border-width:2px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}

.message-text {
  line-height: 75px;
  border-style:solid;
  left: 79px;
  height: 75px;
  border-color: #157EF9;
  border-width:2px;
   width: 500px;
   letter-spacing: 0px;
   text-align: left;
   text-indent: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #555555;
   z-index: 10;
}
.btncontainer {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}
.reloadpage {
  color: #157EF9;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 20;
}
.reloadpage:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.toast-close-button {
  border: none;
  top: 27px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

/*Additional properties for button version
 iOS requires the button element instead of an anchor tag.
 If you want the anchor version, it requires `href="#"`.*/
button.toast-close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' height='512'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgb(255,255,255)' d='M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.toast-close-button:hover,
.toast-close-button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}




/* https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome-Pro/blob/master/advanced-options/raw-svg/regular/info-circle.svg */
.toast-info {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' height='512'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgb(255,255,255)' d='M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 28.74px;
  height: 28.74px;
  padding: 25px;
}
/* https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome-Pro/blob/master/advanced-options/raw-svg/regular/times-circle.svg */
.toast-error {
  background-image: none;
}
/* https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome-Pro/blob/master/advanced-options/raw-svg/regular/check.svg */
.toast-success {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' height='512'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgb(255,255,255)' d='M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 28.74px;
  height: 70px;
  justify-self: center !important;
}
/* https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome-Pro/blob/master/advanced-options/raw-svg/regular/exclamation-triangle.svg */
.toast-warning {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512' width='512' height='512'%3E%3Cpath fill='rgb(255,255,255)' d='M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 28.74px;
  height: 28.74px;
}

.toast-container.toast-top-full-width .ngx-toastr,
.toast-container.toast-bottom-full-width .ngx-toastr {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.ngx-toastr {
  background-color: #030303;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.toast-success {
  background-color: #4C6A13;
}
.toast-error {
  background-color: #800017;
}
.toast-info {
  background-color: #555555;
}
.toast-warning {
  background-color: #FFAE15;
}
.toast-progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your custom toast as [mentioned in the documentation](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr#using-a-custom-toast)

You can follow [this code](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/src/app/pink.toast.ts):

```
import {
  animate,
  keyframes,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger
} from '@angular/animations';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Toast, ToastrService, ToastPackage } from '../lib/public_api';

@Component({
  selector: '[pink-toast-component]',
  styles: [`
    :host {
      background-color: #FF69B4;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 0 6px;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      pointer-events: all;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .btn-pink {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    }
  `],
  template: `
  <div class="row" [style.display]="state.value === 'inactive' ? 'none' : ''">
    <div class="col-9">
      <div *ngIf="title" [class]="options.titleClass" [attr.aria-label]="title">
        {{ title }}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="message && options.enableHtml" role="alert" aria-live="polite"
        [class]="options.messageClass" [innerHTML]="message">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="message && !options.enableHtml" role="alert" aria-live="polite"
        [class]="options.messageClass" [attr.aria-label]="message">
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 text-right">
      <a *ngIf="!options.closeButton" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm" (click)="action($event)">
        {{ undoString }}
      </a>
      <a *ngIf="options.closeButton" (click)="remove()" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">
        close
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="options.progressBar">
    <div class="toast-progress" [style.width]="width + '%'"></div>
  </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('inactive', style({
        opacity: 0,
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('400ms ease-out', keyframes([
        style({
          transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(-30deg)',
          opacity: 0,
        }),
        style({
          transform: 'skewX(20deg)',
          opacity: 1,
        }),
        style({
          transform: 'skewX(-5deg)',
          opacity: 1,
        }),
        style({
          transform: 'none',
          opacity: 1,
        }),
      ]))),
      transition('active => removed', animate('400ms ease-out', keyframes([
        style({
          opacity: 1,
        }),
        style({
          transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(30deg)',
          opacity: 0,
        }),
      ]))),
    ]),
  ],
  preserveWhitespaces: false,
})
export class PinkToast extends Toast {
  // used for demo purposes
  undoString = 'undo';

  // constructor is only necessary when not using AoT
  constructor(
    protected toastrService: ToastrService,
    public toastPackage: ToastPackage,
  ) {
    super(toastrService, toastPackage);
  }

  action(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.undoString = 'undid';
    this.toastPackage.triggerAction();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this. I wonder how I can go about changing the default icons (like for error, warning, etc) with font awesome icons. I was able to before using

 <i class='fas fa-times-circle fa-2x' style='top:30px'></i>

```
within the message, it's just so different than my solution, but I will give it a try. Time is short for me, but we'll see. If it works for me, you got the **win**.
Thanks

Comment: You can override the icon as mentioned here: https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/167

Comment: I have been giving it a try. I have it working as-is, and with slight modifications, but it doesn't look like you can go to far with it. I'll keep at it

Comment: I will say you provided me with the best option. I may still not be able to resize the toastr icons but this is the right path I'm sure. thanks